# Cache configurations of FluentNHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using `FluentNhibernate` version `2.0.3.0` and I'm trying to configure the cache of it to use with `queries`, I'm using `HQL`. I want to one opinion if I did all configurations alright, and I want to know how could I see if cache was activate ?

**Connection**

```
FluentConfiguration _config = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
        MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
            x => x.Server(HOST)
                  .Username(USER)
                  .Password(PASSWORD)
                  .Database(DB)))
    .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass(typeof(NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                 .UseQueryCache())
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UsuarioMap>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg)
    .Execute(false, true));
```

**Mapping**

```
public class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario> {
    public UsuarioMap() {
        Table("USUARIOS");
        Cache.ReadWrite();
        Id(u => u.id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(u => u.nome).Not.Nullable().Length(50);
        Map(u => u.email).Unique().Not.Nullable().Length(255);
        Map(u => u.senha).Not.Nullable();
        Map(u => u.status).CustomType<int>();
        Map(u => u.dtCadastro).CustomType<DateTime>();
        Map(u => u.dtLastLogin).CustomType<DateTime>();
        Map(u => u.tipo).CustomType<int>();
        Map(u => u.imagem);
        Map(u => u.loginBy).CustomType<int>();
        Map(u => u.idFacebook);
    }
}
```

**HQL Query**

```
public class UsuarioDAO : GenericDAO<Usuario>{

    /** retorna todos os objetos */
    public IList<Usuario> findAll(){
        ISession _session = getSession();
        IList<Usuario> list = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Usuario u ORDER BY u.nome")
            .SetCacheable(true).SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal)
            .List<Usuario>();
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A `UseSecondLevelCache` call is very likely missing (xml configuration parameter `cache.use_second_level_cache`).

`HashtableCacheProvider` is [not intended for production use](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-cache), only for test. Choose [another one](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/caches.html).

Transactions do not seem used. At first data change done outside of a transaction, the second level cache will be disabled. Better transacted all session usages.

A `cache.default_expiration` should be configured. This is an integer, in seconds.

You may use session statistics to check if the cache is used. Enable them on the session factory.

```
sessionFactory.Statistics.IsStatisticsEnabled = true;

// Do your stuff then consult the statistics on the session factory.
```

Avoid letting them enabled in production, this incurs some overhead.

**Additional notes:**

If you have some mapped collection you wish to cache, you will have to enable caching for them in their mapping.

Caching works better with lazy-loading. Eager loading may cause cached entities to be reloaded from database instead of being loaded from cache.